# Is there any API in C# for Zooming selected feature?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcobjects

I am new to ArcGIS and want to implement the **Zoom to Selected Features** functionality available in Selection menu option (Selection-> Zoom to Selected Features), using C# API.

Is any API available in C# ?

Comment: Are you using ArcObjects?

Comment: i am using ArcMap.Document

Comment: @DevRaj, This question/anwser is very common and can be found with a simple "arcobjects zoom to selected features c#" google search.  What version of arcgis are you using?

Comment: i am using arcGIS 10.1

Comment: So you are using ArcObjects. Please tag your questions appropriately in the future. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

To implement, I would suggest creating an Add-In (in C#) using ArcObjects API.  Below are some helpful links to get you started:

- [Building add-ins for ArcGIS for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000)
- [Learning ArcObjects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Learning_ArcObjects/0001000000p1000000/)

At the minimum you will need to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express and ArcObjects .NET 10.1 SDK.

An alternative would be to develop a python Add-In.  This option would entail less code, however you may be more limited on available GIS classes/objects.

- [What is a Python add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000)

As I stated in my comment, a web search should give you some source code to start off with.

Comment: Thnx for code sample

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
void ZoomToSelectedFeature(IFeature feature)
{
    IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape;

    IActiveView activeView = ArcMap.Document.ActiveView;
    activeView.Extent = geometry.Envelope;
}

List<IFeature> GetSelectedFeatures(IFeatureLayer selectedFeature)
{
    IFeatureSelection featureSelection = selectedFeature as IFeatureSelection;
    ISelectionSet selectionSet = featureSelection.SelectionSet;
    ICursor cursor ;

    selectionSet.Search(null, false, out cursor);

    IFeatureCursor featureCursor = cursor as IFeatureCursor; 
    IFeature feature = featureCursor.NextFeature();
    List<IFeature> features = new List<IFeature>();
    while (feature != null)
    {
        features.Add(feature);  
        feature = featureCursor.NextFeature();
    }
    return features;
}
```